# Parametric typeclasses

Tags: haskell, typeclass, generic-programming

Is there a way to declare a generic parametrized type `Conf` that offers/provides a function `frames` depending on the type parameter `d`, like

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving
           , MultiParamTypeClasses
           , FunctionalDependencies #-}

import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Identity
import Control.Monad.Trans.Class
import Control.Monad.Trans.State
import Control.Monad.Trans.Except

data MyConf d = MyConf { frames :: [d] } -- my parametric type

-- define a class to expose the interface in monads
class ConfM d m | m -> d where
    getFrames :: m [d]

-- wrap StateT to include MyConf and allow instance of ConfM
newtype MyStateT d m a = MyStateT { runMyStateT :: StateT (MyConf d) m a }
    deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad, MonadTrans)

-- expose the interface over selected transformers
instance Monad m => ConfM d (MyStateT d m) where
    getFrames = MyStateT $ fmap frames get

instance (ConfM d m, Monad m) => ConfM d (ExceptT a m) where
    getFrames = lift getFrames
```

so that then one can write something like:

```
-- hide the gory implementation details
type MyMonad d = ExceptT A (MyStateT d B) C

class SomeClass a

-- this is the desired goal:
-- to concisely write an 'algorithm' in MyMonad only once
-- but for all possible choices of d from SomeClass
example :: SomeClass d => MyMonad d
example = do
    fs <- getFrames
    -- do SomeClass stuff with d
    return ()

-- assume Int is instance of SomeClass
instance SomeClass Int

-- give me an instance of the above generic 'algorithm'
exampleInt :: MyMonad Int
exampleInt = example

-- assuming for example
type A = ()
type B = Identity
type C = ()
```

---

In the above code I am stuck at:

```
test.hs:23:25:
    Illegal instance declaration for ‘ConfM d (MyStateT d m)’
      (All instance types must be of the form (T a1 ... an)
       where a1 ... an are *distinct type variables*,
       and each type variable appears at most once in the instance head.
       Use FlexibleInstances if you want to disable this.)
    In the instance declaration for ‘ConfM d (MyStateT d m)’

test.hs:26:38:
    Illegal instance declaration for ‘ConfM d (ExceptT a m)’
      (All instance types must be of the form (T a1 ... an)
       where a1 ... an are *distinct type variables*,
       and each type variable appears at most once in the instance head.
       Use FlexibleInstances if you want to disable this.)
    In the instance declaration for ‘ConfM d (ExceptT a m)’
```

With additional `FlexibleInstances`

```
test.hs:27:14:
    Illegal instance declaration for ‘ConfM d (ExceptT 
      The coverage condition fails in class ‘ConfM’
        for functional dependency: ‘m -> d’
      Reason: lhs type ‘ExceptT a m’ does not determine
      Using UndecidableInstances might help
    In the instance declaration for ‘ConfM d (ExceptT a
```

---

So I need `UndecidableInstances`.

Comment: is the `getDs` supposed to be `forall d . getDs :: m [d]`? Probably not - so maybe you could have a look at type-families or functional dependencies to assoziate the type with your `m`

Comment: That sounds like what I am after, although at this point I have no idea what you just said :), thanks for the pointers

Comment: have a look at the [wiki on type families](https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC/Type_families#An_associated_data_type_example) - I think this is very similar to what you want to do here

Comment: you basically would at `type ElemType m` and `getDs :: m [ElemType m]` to the `class` and `type ElemType  (MyState (Conf d) m) = d` to the instance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question seems a bit vague, but it sounds like a potential use case for a multi-parameter typeclass with a functional dependency.

```
{-# LANGUAGE  MultiParamTypeClasses
            , FunctionalDependencies #-}

class Monad m => MyClass d m | m -> d where
  getDs :: m [d]
```

Then `MyClass d m` means that `m` is a `Monad` and that `getDs` can be used to produce a value of type `m [d]`. The purpose of the functional dependency is to indicate that `m` *determines* `d`. There is exactly one instance declaration of `MyClass` for each `m`, and that class must determine what `d` is. So you could write an instance like

```
instance MyClass Int IO where ...
```

(which would then be the *only* one allowed for `IO`), but not something wishy-washy like

```
instance MyClass d IO where ...
```

because the latter does not determine `d`.

---

You might find my choice of argument order for `MyClass` a bit strange. There is some method to this madness. The main reason for it is that `MyClass` can be partially applied. Partially applying it to `m` isn't too useful, because that leaves a constraint that can only be satisfied by one possible argument. Partially applying it to `d`, on the other hand, could be useful, because there could be multiple choices of `m` for a given choice of `d`. Thus given `{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds #-}`,

```
type MakesInts = MyClass Int
```

is a potentially useful constraint. I believe using this order *may* also help avoid the need for `UndecidableInstances` in some cases, but I'm not certain.

---

An alternative others mentioned is to use an associated type family.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

class Monad m => MyClass m where
  type Available m
  getDs :: m [Available m]
```

This does essentially the same thing, but

1. Anyone writing an instance of `MyClass` must include a line like, e.g., `type Available IO = Int`.
2. Anyone placing a constraint on the `Available` type will need to use `Available` in the constraint, and will need `FlexibleContexts` (not a big deal).
3. The type family offers access to the associated type.
4. Type families are expressed in GHC Core (AKA System FC), so they're better-behaved than functional dependencies in some regards.

1 (especially) and 2 are arguably downsides of the type family approach; 3 and 4 are upsides. This largely comes down to a question of taste.

Comment: how could i improve my question?

Comment: Another advantage to the order of type parameters of the class is you can `derive` that class for a type with GND or DeriveAnyClass, but you can't do so with the parameters switched around, nor with an associated type (but you can fix it in the latter case by simply moving the type family out of the class).

Comment: I would actually need this wishy-washy `instance MyClass d (... d)`. Is there a reason why this should not be possible to do?

Comment: @jd823592, that should be fine.

Comment: @dfeuer, I must be doing something else wrong, see the error messages. I thought it was because this wishy-washy thing was wrong.

Comment: @jd823592, this time GHC is telling you the truth. You need to enable `FlexibleInstances`. Both that extension and `FlexibleContexts` are very often necessary when using multi-parameter type classes.

Comment: @dfeuer, sry that this starts to look like chat, but there are further errors and I really have no idea what to do about it :/ The description of `FlexibleContexts` seems unrelated (to this example) so I did not try that.

Comment: @jd823592, try doing what it says and add `UndecidableInstances`. It sounds scary, but it's a very safe extension. (The worst it does is let you make mistakes that cause the type checker to go into an infinite loop.) The main extensions to *avoid* when GHC mentions them are `OverlappingInstances`, `IncoherentInstances`, and `ImpredicativeTypes`. Others are generally fine.

Comment: @jd823592, oh yeah, and `AllowAmbiguousTypes` is generally only good to turn on temporarily to try to move type errors from place to place.